# Android,Spring and Json General Questions?

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I want to consult a thing,
Actually,It is  a suggestion from you .
I have a project that was created with spring 3.0,JSF 2.0,Hibernate and PrimeFaces.
This project has a mobile platform also,
Problem is starting here. 
What is your suggestion to connect android platform for getting and sending data?
android platform's functionally is the same as web platform's.
Data as JSON or XML(Web Service)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Android is capable of using both JSON and XML though. We'd have to know more about what you're trying to do to be able to tell you much more than that both are possible.

Comment: Which one is the best way to send data and get data?JSon or XML

Comment: There isn't a "best" way. Both work fine. To choose what might work better or worse we'd have to know specifically what type of data you are going to be sending.

Comment: Generally, I will send data as List<Category>,Category that is Hibernate Entity and vice versa.Before I heard "Json data is more quickly sending than XML data",for this reason I asked this question.

Comment: JSON tends to end up being a smaller amount of raw text which would cause it to transmit quicker. XML is able to tell you more about the data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your own Oauth postmethod which would return a JSONObject. sending POST and GET requests are easy enough to do.

for example...

```
public static HttpResponse SendGet(String Url, HashMap<String, 
                     String> hm, DefaultHttpClient httpClient) {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    if (hm == null) return null;
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(Url);
            response = httpClient.execute(getMethod); 
            return response;
}
```

Then you can handle the httpresponse with somethign similar to...

```
BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = handler.handleResponse(httpresponse);
j = new JSONObject(response);
```

So things you could add are token and userid to the get request

```
Url = Url+"?token="token; //etc
```

also you can easily convert this to a post request and send the oauth params via the post body. There is plenty of tutorials/info available online.